# Using Javascript to do magical stuff with HTML or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm in the process of creating a Chrome extension that overrides a sites CSS. I want to try to add an icons next to each menu item using [Typicons](http://typicons.com/). Below is the code they use for their menu.

```
<ul class="standAloneNavItems">
    <li class="selected">
        <a href="/cgi-bin/home43535">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="unselected">
        <a href="/cgi-bin/mail75653">Mailbox </a>
    </li>
    <li class="unselected">
        <a href="/cgi-bin/account23544">My Account </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The link changes every time so CSS selectors weren't an option.

```
a[href$="/cgi-bin/account"] { content: '\e080'; !important; }
```

I'm not much of a Javascript guy but I'm wondering if it's possible to use them in some way to target the names and add HTML or CSS through there.

Comment: Why don't you just add it at `.standAloneNavItems li` selector?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I would like to have a different icon for each menu item.

Comment: Then you should assign different CSS class to each `li`

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Their HTML isn't in my power.

Comment: You can only change CSS ? Oops. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention jQuery, you can use the [jQuery `contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to:

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.

For instance you can select all anchor elements containing "Home" and color them red like this:

```
$('a:contains("Home")').css({
  'color': 'red',
  'background-color':'gray'
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Acp2B/1/)

Comment: You can chain on whatever you'd like, more css, etc- updated demo (showing two approaches):  http://jsfiddle.net/Acp2B/3/

Comment: One more thing, is !important an option?

Comment: Here's a good overview on `!important`:  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: I'm trying to override their CSS. If I don't use !important it usually never does anything.

Comment: It depends on the rest of their css since it's a way to force that css to take priority.  If that css was already the controlling css then it doesn't matter- but if the !important gave it priority it wouldn't otherwise have had, then it'll matter.  So it really depends...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and regex to match your requirement

```
$('.standAloneNavItems li a').filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('href').match(/\/cgi-bin\/account/);
    }).css({'background-color': 'red'});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/2q5gt/)**

Comment: The link changes every time. The word in the link /account/ sometimes isn't there.

Comment: What is constant throughout, is it text like Home, My Account? I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: It's just /cgi-bin/ and a random string of numbers and letters. The menu items stay the same name.

Comment: Then you can update $(this).attr('href') to $(this).text).match('Account')

Answer (score 0):

Since you want an icon for every menu, you can try this

```
<ul class="standAloneNavItems">
        <li id="image1" class="selected">
           <a href="/cgi-bin/home43535">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li id="image2" class="unselected">
            <a href="/cgi-bin/mail75653">Mailbox </a>
        </li>


           <li id="image3" class="unselected">
           <a href="/cgi-bin/account23544">My Account </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

And in the CSS:

```
#image1 { content: '\e080'; !important; }
#image3 { content: '\e080'; !important; }
#image3 { content: '\e080'; !important; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Their HTML isn't in my power.